# QTableView - set the first column as "read only"

Tags: qt, qtableview

I have a QTableView based on a QStandardItemModel. 
I want to set the first column as "read only" and all the others columns editable.

I'm not an expert of QT and OOP, i searched around the web and in the QT-documentation and I've understand that I need to reimplement the flags(const QModelIndex &index) function of my model, but I don't know how and where do the re-implementation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so what have you got so far?

Comment: I think the re-implementation should looks like this:

    if (index.column() == 1) {
        return QAbstractModel::flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsEditable;
    }
But i don't know where to put this piece of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a new class inherited from `QStandardItemModel`, reimplement method `flags` and use your new class instead of the standard one.

```
class MyModel : public QStandardItemModel
{
public:
    virtual Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex& index) const override
    {
       Qt::ItemFlags result = QStandardItemModel::flags(index);
       if (index.column() == 0) //0 is the first column!
       {
           result &= ~Qt::ItemIsEditable;
       }
       return result;
    }
}
```

Another way to do the same:
- create a new class inherited from `QStandardItem`,
- reimplement `flags` in the same way
- call `QStandardItemModel::setItemPrototype` with an instance of the new class
This way is a little bit more complicated because you will need to reimplement method `QStandardItem::clone` as well.

Comment: Do you mean `result |= ~Qt::ItemIsEditable;` ? I think OR operator is what we are looking for

Comment: @sami1592 no, we should remove `editable` flag. `|=` will enable all the flags instead